# Reals to integers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integers

Do you think the following is true or not?

Let $x,y,\epsilon \in \mathbb{R^{+ \star}}$. Can I find $\tilde{\epsilon}$ such that $\tilde{\epsilon}<\epsilon$ and both $\frac{x}{\tilde{\epsilon}}$ and $\frac{y}{\tilde{\epsilon}}$ are integers?

If it's false, do you think it can be true with an additional assumption on $x,y$ (being rationnal or integer)?

I would also like to generalize to a finite familly of real numbers $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\epsilon$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's $\mathbb{R^{+ \star}}$?

Comment: Strictly positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: if both $x/\tilde{\epsilon}, y/\tilde{\epsilon}$ are integers, then their quotient is a rational number. But their quotient is $x/y$...

Comment: Thank you! If $x,y$ are rational, do you think it is possible?

Comment: Of course. If $h,k$ are the denominators of $x,y$ respectively, then take $\tilde{\epsilon} = 1/(ahk)$  where $a \ge 1$ is a large enough number.